# Firestore: Access documents in collection user has permission to

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection called announcements that I'm using to store data. However each document has a field called "permissions" that contains a permission level string. I wrote function to determine if a user has access based on their permission level and that of the resource.

When I setup a onSnapshot callback for a single document that should work I get the response. Once I switch it to the get the snapshot of the collection it gets an invalid permissions error. Based on what I could find, firestore fails if there is a chance that a user doesn't have access to any of the documents in a collection. What is the model in which I should use? How can I get the documents that user's should have access too?

Rules

```
match /chapters/{chapter} {
        function isMember() {
          return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/chapters/$(chapter)/members/$(request.auth.uid))
      }

      function getUser() {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chapters/$(chapter)/members/$(request.auth.uid))
      }

      function hasPermission(userPermission, documentPermission) {
        return documentPermission == "all" || userPermission == "admin" || userPermission == documentPermission
      }

        allow read: if isMember()

      match /announcements/{announcement} {
        allow read: if isMember() && hasPermission(getUser().data.permissions, resource.data.permissions)
      }
}
```

Works vvv

```
firestore.collection("chapters").doc("chapter-1").collection("announcements").doc("doc1").onSnapshot(doc => {
                const announcements = doc.data()

                console.log(announcements)
        })
```

Doesn't work vvv

```
 firestore.collection("chapters").doc("chapter-1").collection("announcements").onSnapshot(docs => {
            docs.forEach(doc => {
                const announcements = doc.data()

                console.log(announcements)
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, in the case of queries, **rules are not filter**.

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query),

> When writing queries to retrieve documents, keep in mind that security
>   rules are not filters—queries are all or nothing.

You need to **"write your queries to fit the constraints of your security rules"**.

On the other hand,

> this behavior applies to queries that retrieve one or more documents
>   from a collection and **not to individual document retrievals**. When you
>   use a document ID to retrieve a single document, Cloud Firestore reads
>   the document and evaluates the request using your security rules and
>   the actual document properties.

This is why it works when you query only one doc with

`firestore.collection("chapters").doc("chapter-1").collection("announcements").doc("doc1").onSnapshot()`

---

So for querying the collection, you need to add a filter to your query as follows:

```
firestore.collection("chapters").doc("chapter-1").collection("announcements").where("permissions", "==", "xxxxx");
```

Comment: Thank you, this breakdown is what I needed. Is it possible to check if a document(parent_doc) has another doc(child_doc) in it's sub collection using this where clause?

Comment: Nope, not with the `where()` method, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#where ("'Creates and returns a new Query with the additional filter that documents must contain the specified field and the value should satisfy the relation constraint provided."). You may add an extra field in your document that holds the same information than the one of the child doc.

Comment: Note that it is interesting to watch the official video on Firestore security rules: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw. at 14min20 you will see the explanations corresponding to the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to form a 'where" clause where I check if a map contains a key? I know this can be done for an array, but I'd like to (if possible) store a map of key value pairs with the key being the user's id and the value being an object with a few details. I see array-contains as an options, but I dont know how to do something like "members.keys() array-contains <uid>"

Comment: @AustinE Did you ever find an answer to your question? I'd like to do something like that too.